# Frequently repeated threads in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm building a barcode scanner which, different from other implementations, does the scanning part continuously in the background rather than waiting the user to trigger the process.

Now, the most (or what I think is the most) obvious way to achieve this is to process the scanning part in another thread to make sure that the main thread won't be interrupted. So that the user won't be bothered with UI lags, stutters, and whatnot.

I'm not the brightest guy when it comes to concurrency. But I've did my homework and done some research about it which, in turn has lead me to write this:

```
...
mScannerExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
...

Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

        final Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
        barcode.setData(data);

        Runnable scan = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int result = mBarcodeScanner.scanImage(barcode);
                if (result != 0) {
                    if(isInPreview) {
                        isInPreview = false;
                        mCamera.stopPreview();
                    }

                    SymbolSet symbolSet = mBarcodeScanner.getResults();
                    mListener.onBarcodeScanned(symbolSet.iterator().next());
                    if (enableRepeatedScanning) {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(restartPreview, mRescanIntervalMillis);
                    }
                 }
            }
        };
        mScannerExecutor.execute(scan);
    }
};
```

But the above code has been causing a lot of error in its execution. I can't even keep the app running for more than a mere couple of seconds. The error message varies from time to time, but this below was shown the most:

```
Fatal signal 8 (SIGFPE), code -6, fault addr 0x17b8 in tid 6410 (pool-1-thread-1)
```

I have a strong feeling that this design in general is heavily flawed. Thus the constant crashing.

What can I do to make this right? Did I miss something really important here?

---

***p.s.,*** The `previewCallback` defined above will be called *very* frequently; once every 2000ms (2 secs).

Comment: Mmmm, if your run loop (i.e. scan(...)) is taking more than 2000ms you are possibly going to run into problems with the camera. As a quick test - reduce your thread pool size down to 1 so that scans run sequentially.

Comment: Whoa, that worked! Well, some sort. Now the app only crashed when a barcode is scanned. Could my call to the listener caused this? LogCat doesn't gave me anything..

Comment: Guessing wildly - but the data parameter is not marked as final and it is used in barcode.setData() which is then accessed from inside the thread. Two suggestions - move the new Image stuff into the scan method and put a try .. catch(Throwable) around everything inside the scan method and log the exception. And make sure your logcat isn't being filtered by e.g. your own tags

Comment: The LogCat shows that it was an OutOfMemoryException that broke my app. Weird, if the executor only allowed one thread to run at a time, shouldn't all be just OK? Cause, when running above code in the UI thread the app run without a problem, despite being very slow.